# How to fix The operation is neither 'array op array' when using cv2.absdiff

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I am trying to find out the difference retrieved from the same video by defining 2 frame. I am new to python and opencv. I been following the tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkcUgPhOlP8&list=WL&index=9&t=136s .

This is the error popped up.

> OpenCV(4.1.1)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:663:
>   error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is
>   neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same
>   number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in
>   function 'cv::arithm_op'

I found similar questions asked in StackOverflow but that question is referring to an image. I am not sure how to implement it in my code.
Here's the link that I found [OpenCV - Sizes of input arguments do not match - addWeighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888388/opencv-sizes-of-input-arguments-do-not-match-addweighted)

...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\768x576.avi')
frame_width = int( cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

frame_height =int( cap.get( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')

out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 5.0, (768,576))


ret, frame1 = cap.read()
ret, frame2 = cap.read()
print(frame1.shape)
print(frame2.shape)
while cap.isOpened():
    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 800:
            continue
        cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    image = cv2.resize(frame1, (768,576))
    out.write(image)
    cv2.imshow("feed", frame1)
    frame1 = frame2
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()

    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
out.release()
```

...

I am expecting no error since I followed everything in the video.

Comment: You must ensure the capture is successful for both frames before doing the absdiff operation.

Comment: My suggestion is to post your entire code, because, as zeFrenchy says, most probably one of your frame is not good(or maybe both) : indeed the error message says the types of the variables passed to absDiff are not matching

Comment: @zeFrenchy does printing out the shape of it show the success of capturing it? If it does, I'm indeed having it before while loop.

Comment: @MauroDorni I have edited my post, this is my whole code. Can you please help me check it?

Comment: First, move cap reads inside the loop, to actually update the analyzed frames. Then check, just after cap init, if cap is actually working a.k.a checking if cap.isOpened() returns True: potentially it could "just" be a missing video codec...

Comment: After moving in cap reads inside the loop. The cap.isOpened() returns True after cap init. I tested it  also inside the loop returns True as well. But I'm having problem at gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) having error of 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: You should check `ret` after each `cap.read()` to make sure you got a frame. Check if both frames are valid when things go wrong ... most likely you are getting bad input.

Comment: You are right, my ret returns false for both frames just before errors. Any suggestions for solutions?

Comment: @zeFrenchy thanks for your advice, i finally solved it. It returns false because the video had been processed until it last frame, i'll just have to stop it when it ends.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for an answer, here is how you solve it.

```
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
print(ret)
ret, frame2 = cap.read()
print(ret)

while cap.isOpened():
    if ret==False:
        print(ret)
        break
```

As @zeFrenchy and @Mauro Dorni pointed out, the reason for the error is due to the video cap ending, and cv2 still trying to capture it even after the end.