# Problem with openCV Mat "Sizes of input arguments do not match"

Tags: c++, opencv

```
Mat newMask = Mat::zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());

for (int i=0; i< 3; i++){
    Mat tray = Mat::zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());
    inRange(mask,i+1, i+1, tray);
    cv::erode(tray, tray, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5)), cv::Point(-1, -1));
    newMask += tray;
}
```

That method should work?

I get a crash:

> Sizes of input arguments do not match)
>   The operation is neither 'array op
>   array' (where arrays have the same
>   size and the same number of channels),
>   nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op
>   array' in function 'arithm_op'

At the line below:

```
newMask += tray;
```

Comment: Does it crash there if you remove one or both of the middle lines i.e. inRange and/or cv::erode?

Comment: if crash on this line "newMask += tray;". when I comment two previous I get another kind of crash

Answer (score 0):

The channel numbers of your images are different. Thats the reason. You can simply change your code like this:

```
Mat newMask = Mat::zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());

cvtColor(newMask,newMask,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    for (int i=0; i< 3; i++){
        Mat tray = Mat::zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());
        inRange(mask,i+1, i+1, tray);
        cv::erode(tray, tray, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5)), cv::Point(-1, -1));
        newMask += tray;
    }
```

You can also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888388/opencv-sizes-of-input-arguments-do-not-match-addweighted/13950990) which is mentioned the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yunus,

now this code:

```
+ (Vec3f)getFeats:(Mat&)mask {
    Mat newMask = Mat::zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());

    cvtColor(newMask,newMask,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        for (int i=0; i< 3; i++){
            Mat tray = Mat::zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());
            inRange(mask,i+1, i+1, tray);
            cv::erode(tray, tray, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5)), cv::Point(-1, -1));
            newMask += tray;
        }

    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    findContours( newMask, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    vector<float> v;
    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){
        v.push_back(cv::contourArea(contours[i])/(mask.size[0]*mask.size[1]));
    }

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<float>());
    return Vec3f(v[0], v[1], v[2]);
}
```

crash on last line:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)